# LazyInitialisationException - failed to lazily initialise a collection of role

Tags: java, database, hibernate

The purpose of this code is to allow a user to check an ID; in this case it would be an ID to check a competition of a specific sport, in order to view the relevant match and it's details. The whole purpose of doing this was to inform the user that if they had entered an incorrect ID, I simply wanted to generate a message within the SOAP request informing that the entered competitionID was incorrect. When I am debugging my code, I am faced with an error "LazyInitialisationException: failed to lazily initialise a collection of role", any ideas?

```
public void CompetitionIdChecker(Set<RestrictionFailure> failures, CompetitionSetup competition) {
    Long compId21 = Long.valueOf(competition.getCompetitionId());
    try {
        Node competitionNode = nodeDao.findById(competition.getCompetitionId());
        Set<Node> childNodes = competitionNode.getChildNodes();
        Iterator<Node> nodeItr = childNodes.iterator();
        Node feedNode = nodeItr.next();
        Feed incidentFeed = competition.getIncidentProvider();
        Node Node = null;
        if (incidentFeed.name().equalsIgnoreCase(feedNode.getSys().getCode())) {
            Node = feedNode.findLinkedNode(new SystemKey(incidentFeed.name()));
        }
        if (Node != null) {
            // as node is set as final level in nodes hierarchy
            if (Node.getChildNodes().size() > 0) {
                System.out.println("it is not valid");
                failures.add(new RestrictionFailure("Competition ID does not exist in Nodes table"));
            } else {
                System.out.println("compId is valid");
            }

        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        LOGGER.error("Error getting competition id", e);
        // rollback(tx);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The default mapping of a many-to-one relation is set to lazy loading. This means that child nodes are not queried when you get the parent object. This makes sense because otherwise you would query all relations of a parent object even if you would never use it. So when you access such child objects you get a LazyLoadingException.
To overcome this you can either set the mapping to non-lazy or make a query that fetches the children. Please take a look at fetch joins. https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/reference/de-DE/html/queryhql.html#queryhql-joins